# XML::LibXML issue finding XML nodes with a namespace

Tags: xml, perl, url, xml-parsing, xml-libxml

I am writing an XML parser and am having an issue with the program handling a link. I am attempting to parse an XML hierarchy Settings/Setting then findnode 'Value'. The following is an example of the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<Settings xmlns='http://hme.com/Settings.xsd'>
  <Setting SID="0">
    <Name>Store ID</Name>
    <Value>72</Value>
  </Setting>
  <Setting SID="1">
    <Name>Deprecated</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </Setting>
  <Setting SID="8">
    <Name>Open Store Hours Sunday</Name>
    <Value>25200</Value>
  </Setting>
```

Here is the code I am using to parse the XML

```
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($settings_file) or die "Couldn't parse timer settings\n";

#Sunday
for my $reviewer ($doc->findnodes('/Settings/Setting[@SID="8"]')) {
  my ($name) = $reviewer->findnodes('Value');
  $name->removeChildNodes();
  $name->appendText('109800');
}
```

When I remove the `xmlns='http://hme.com/Settings.xsd'` from the XML file, there is no issue with replacing the value node. Once I enter the link back in the XML, the code stops working and will not update the xml sheet. Is there a way to handle for this link or to remove it so I can properly update the file?

Comment: You might find the "[Working with namespaces](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/namespaces.html)" section from my tutorial useful.

Comment: Looking over the page you suggested I believe I am declaring the namespace correcr but am getting an `XPath error: Undefined namespace prefix`. I used the xpath sandbox and was able to load in my xml and use the query to find the node but when I attempt in my code no luck.

This is how im declaring the namespace
`my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs('xsd', 'http://hme.com/Settings.xsd');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask to find nodes with namespace null and with name `Settings`. There are no such nodes in the document, so `findnodes` correctly returns nothing.

You want to find the nodes with namespace `http://hme.com/Settings.xsd` and with name `Settings`. You can use the following to achieve that:

```
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs( s => 'http://hme.com/Settings.xsd' );

for ($xpc->findnodes('/s:Settings/s:Setting[@SID="8"]'), $doc) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using this code.

```
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs('xsd',  'http://hme.com/Settings.xsd');

my($match1) = $xpc->findnodes('//xsd:Settings/xsd:Setting[@SID="8"]/xsd:Value');
$match1->removeChildNodes();
$match1->appendText('23400');
```

Comment: If anyone is looking at this in the future and needs help, this tool helped me alot.
https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/_static/xpath-sandbox/xpath-sandbox.html?q=//dublin%3Atitle;filename=xml-libxml.svg;xmlns:dublin=http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/

Comment: That's the same thing I posted 3 days earlier (except you made it a lot worse by using `//` instead of `/`).

Comment: @ikegami sorry I made it "a lot worse" I wasn't getting it to work with your code. Could be user error, I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: The code is identical except in two places: 1) You used `xsd` instead of `s` as the prefix, but choice of prefix doesn't matter. 2) You used `//` instead of `/`, which is very expensive for no reason, and it could lead to incorrect results.

Comment: @ikegami thats my bad I guess, like I said I am no expert today and was even less so 3 years ago.